# Using Foundation_EXPORT correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a file called Event.h:

```
@interface Event : NSObject

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const KP_STATUS_NEW
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const KP_STATUS_APPROVED
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const KP_STATUS_DELETED

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * status
```

I would like programmers who use my SDK to have access to the `STATUS` strings especially when setting a status for an Event object. Should I be using FOUNDATION_EXPORT like the above?

So that a programmer can just do

```
Event * myEvent = [[Event alloc] init];
myEvent.status = STATUS_NEW;
```

?

Is that the way to do it in objective-c?

By the way KP is the common prefix for the project. Should I be prefixing the status with KP or something else? What's the standard?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `extern`, rather than `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` (which I believe is what it is defined as anyway).

Using a common prefix is a good idea, given the lack of namespaces in Objective-C and this goes double for a class called `Event` which is a very common name.

So something like this, looks OK to me:

```
#import "KPEvent.h"

KPEvent * myEvent = [[KPEvent alloc] init];
myEvent.status = KP_STATUS_NEW;
```

or better still:

```
myEvent.status = KP_EVENT_STATUS_NEW;
```

if statuses only relate to the event class.

What you don't explain, is why you cannot use an `enum`, which is more elegant:

```
typedef enum {
    KP_EVENT_STATUS_NEW,
    KP_EVENT_STATUS_APPROVED,
    KP_EVENT_STATUS_DELETED
} KpEventStatus;
```

and you can forget about that `extern` nonsense.

Comment: The advantage of `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` over just `extern` is that it also works correctly when C++ imports the header. (It also works correctly on Windows, but that's very seldom a concern.) That said, I almost always just use `extern`.